# Searching a CSV file using python. Need bool and str parameters

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

Data Frame is named "df_fraud"

Below are the columns in csv file

`accountAgeDays,numItems,localTime,paymentMethod,paymentMethodAgeDays,label`

I need all fraudulent transactions, which used paypal.

```
df_fraud[df_fraud.paymentMethod =='paypal']
```

This returns there are 9303 paypal transactions

Here, `1=fraudulent`, `0=safe` :

```
df_fraud[df_fraud.label == 1]
```

Returns there are 560 fraudulent transactions

How do I write a line of code to output all fraudulent transactions which used paypal?

```
df_fraud[df_fraud.paymentMethod =='paypal' and df_fraud.babel == 1]
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I am relatively new in this space, could someone explain this error or how to achieve what I want to achieve with explanation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply merge the filter with the `&` character like this:

```py
df_fraud[(df_fraud.paymentMethod =='paypal') & (df_fraud.label == 1)]
```